# how i can remove type js from tag

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, html, script

I need to remove JS-type from my script tag(s) for optimization. I am using magento 1.9, and this is a response to the following error:

thank you
[image]

Comment: You don't *need* to, it's a warning not an error. The type attribute is still valid as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by rewriting `getCssJsHtml` method inside `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`. This method is responsible for adding all the JS & CSS files defined via layout, into your page.

Inside this method, you can see the static built up of `<script>` tags, where, you'll need to then remove the type attribute.

Comment: thank u prateek ur helped me a lot